# rm: cannot remove `/../...v': Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, rm, permission-denied

I want to delete directory `982899`. It is located under directory `big`.
When I first try to delete `982899`, it shows many lines of messages like this:

> rm: cannot remove `982899/.../...v': Permission denied

So I use `chmod 777 .` to make directory `big` be able to change everything.

However, after it, `rm -rf 982899` still shows the same messages:

> rm: cannot remove `982899/.../...v': Permission denied

I even executed `chmod 777 982899`, but nothing changed!

Why ? What should I do to delete directory `982899`?

Comment: `chmod -R 777 982899`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rm -rf 982899` will try to recursively remove anything inside that directory, and then, once it is empty, remove the directory itself. So your problem may be that you do not have permission to delete the items inside `982899`. You can try to `chmod -R 777 982899`, or `chown -R <your_user> 982899` to get around this. Be careful though that `chxxx` commands use an uppercase `-R` for recursive operation.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the below message:

> rm: cannot remove `982899/.../...v': Permission denied

was caused as the `owner` of the file is another user (e.g. `root`).

This can be solved by running as `root` by using `sudo`

```
sudo rm -rf 982899
```

Comment: I copied 982899 from other place to my directory. I'm not in the sudoers file, So I can't use sudo rm -rf 982899 . Is there another way?

Comment: what is the result of running `ls -lsa 982899/.../...v` ?

Comment: If you can't use `sudo`, then you might be able to switch to root with `su`, then try `rm -r 982899` again.  If you have no root access, then you need to contact the administrator of the machine.

Comment: hoe is right@Yaron I have remove the directory successfully.

Comment: @YuanWen great :)